# What should I do to answer an old closed question that should have been merged to an other stackexchange site?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866598/good-alternatives-to-sandcastle-to-generate-msdn-style-documentation) should be merged to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead of closed. I want to add a new answer to it and don't know what should I do.

Comment: [done](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39227/alternatives-to-sandcastle).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the question really is a good question for Software Recommendations, then you can always simply ask the question yourself. That is, post this question over there.

*Please be aware* of the conditional in my first sentence. From your profile, I see that you only have your association rep on SR, and you have no questions or answers there. So be advised that you may not be the best judge for what is and is not a good question for SR.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I can tell what is a good question for SR even if I have no rep on it. And should I copy and paste other old answers from the old question into my answer on SR, for the completeness?

Comment: @zwcloud do you have an interest of seeing this question answered?

Comment: @Braiam I was just asking what should be done in that situation. And this answer will help others, who are also hesitating, to make a proper choice.

Comment: @zwcloud if you have interest on seeing this information around, you can simply ask the question; but if you aren't interested, then doing nothing will be more productive to you, as in SR, they could ask for clarification, or more details, which if you don't have interest into what you are asking for, will be weird to provide.

Comment: Oh.. you mean that question. I think it is good to answer my own question,  which is also encouraged. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ And my intent is to *document it in public*. But thanks for your concern! @Braiam